# How do I retain the outer XML of sub-elements?

Tags: go

I have an XML file that contains a list of individual `<order/>` elements. I would like to split this single XML file up into multiple files, each of which contain a single order.

Example input file:

```xml
<orders>
  <order order-id="123">
    <line-item product-id="ABC">ABC</line-item>
  </order>
  <order order-id="456">
    <line-item product-id="DEF">DEF</line-item>
  </order>
</orders>
```

Desired outputs:

> Order-123.xml:
>
> ```
>  <order order-id="123">
>    <line-item product-id="ABC">ABC</line-item>
>  </order>
> ```
>
> Order-456.xml:
>
> ```
>  <order order-id="456">
>    <line-item product-id="DEF">DEF</line-item>
>  </order>
> ```

At this stage, I am not concerned with unmarshalling each of the order details into a struct; I merely want an exact copy of each `<order/>` node in its own file.

I have tried a few variations of this using `xml:",innerxml"`, [like this](https://play.golang.org/p/zWb_Dxn4FW):

```golang
type OrdersRaw struct {
  Orders []OrderRaw `xml:"order"`
}

type OrderRaw struct {
  Order string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

The problem in the above code is that each `Order` value contains the inner XML (starting with `<line-item/>`) but does not contain the wrapping `<order/>` tag.

Ideally, if there were an `xml:",outerxml"` tag, it would serve my purpose.

I am trying to avoid doing hacky things like manually concatenating the inner XML with handwritten XML (e.g. `<order order-id="123">`).

Comment: Seems it can be done with just regexp.

Comment: Parsing XML with a regular expression? Just because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_. I'm trying to avoid [hacky solutions like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: In simple cases regexp can be faster and more readable than XML Encoder Decoder pipe

Comment: Did you find any generic solution to get a copy of the original outerxml when parsing into a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `XMLName` on your `OrderRaw`:

```
type OrderRaw struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"order"`
    Order   string   `xml:",innerxml"`
    OrderID string   `xml:"order-id,attr"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/onK5FExqzD.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to save *all* attributes, you'll have to use `MarshalerXML` and `UnmarshalerXML` interfaces:

```
func (o *OrderRaw) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    o.attrs = map[xml.Name]string{}
    for _, a := range start.Attr {
        o.attrs[a.Name] = a.Value
    }
    type order OrderRaw
    return d.DecodeElement((*order)(o), &start)
}

func (o OrderRaw) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    for name, attr := range o.attrs {
        start.Attr = append(start.Attr, xml.Attr{Name: name, Value: attr})
    }
    start.Name = xml.Name{Local: "order"}
    type order OrderRaw
    return e.EncodeElement(order(o), start)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/XhkwqJFyMd.

Comment: Thanks, that's close, but I'm hoping for a solution that captures the full outer xml of each order, in case an attribute is added (e.g. `<order order-id="123" foo="bar"/>`) in the future without my knowledge.